# Deleting function call error?

Tags: python

I'm trying to program mastermind (the game), and in my `for` loop on this line::

```
del cpureturn(rndm_cpureturn)
```

I keep getting the same error:

`SyntaxError: can't delete function call`

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
#Mastermind
import random as r
import sys


#Color Database
colorpegs = ['blue', 'black', 'red', 'white', 'yellow', 'green']
correctingpegs = ['White', 'Black']

#CPU Code Generator

code1 = r.choice(colorpegs)
code2 = r.choice(colorpegs)
code3 = r.choice(colorpegs)
code4 = r.choice(colorpegs)

cpucode = [code1, code2, code3, code4]

#Player Guessing

print('')
print('')
print('Colors: Blue, Black, Red, White, Yellow, Green')


guessround = 1 #Says what try, For amount of tries
print(cpucode)

while guessround <= 10:

    print('')
    print('Guess Round %s / 10' %(guessround))

    guess1 = input('Guess code color 1: ') #Inputting Colors
    guess2 = input('Guess code color 2: ')
    guess3 = input('Guess code color 3: ')
    guess4 = input('Guess code color 4: ')

    print('')
    print('Your guesses were: %s %s %s %s ' % (guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4))

    cpureturn = [] #Step1 to cpureturn randomization

    if guess1 == cpucode[0]: #Guess 1
        cpureturn.append('Black')

    elif guess1 == cpucode[1] or guess1 == cpucode[2] or guess1 == cpucode[3] and guess1 != code1:
    cpureturn.append('White')

    else:
        cpureturn.append('Nothing')



    if guess2 == cpucode[1]:#Guess2
        cpureturn.append('Black')

    elif guess2 == cpucode[0] or guess2 == cpucode[2] or guess2 == cpucode[3] and guess2 != code2:
        cpureturn.append('White')

    else:
        cpureturn.append('Nothing')



    if guess3 == cpucode[2]:#Guess3
        cpureturn.append('Black')

    elif guess3 == cpucode[1] or guess3 == cpucode[0] or guess3 == cpucode[3] and guess3 != code3: 
        cpureturn.append('White')

    else:
        cpureturn.append('Nothing')


    if guess4 == cpucode[3]:#guess4
        cpureturn.append('Black')

    elif guess4 == cpucode[1] or guess4 == cpucode[2] or guess4 == code4[0]:
        cpureturn.append('White')

    else:
        cpureturn.append('Nothing')

    for i in range(1, 5):   
        rndm_cpureturn = (r.choice(cpureturn))
        print(rndm_cpureturn)
        del cpureturn(rndm_cpureturn)

    if guess1 == code1 and guess2 == code2 and guess3 == code3 and guess4 == code4 and guessround != 10 :        
        print('')
        print('')
        print('')
        print('WE HAVE A WINNER')
        sys.exit()


    if guessround == 10: 
        print('You Lose, better luck next time')
        print('The code was' + cpucode)    
        sys.exit()

    guessround = guessround + 1
```

Comment: But what would `del cpureturn(rndm_cpureturn)` even mean? Instead of dumping the program, please explain what's happening, and what you want the several parts of the program to do?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the variable cpureturn? If not, what do you want that line of code to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to delete a particular element (by its value, not its position) in `cpureturn`. To do that, use the `remove` method:

```
cpureturn.remove(rndm_cpureturn)
```

Note that `del` works by specifying an index:

```
i = r.randrange(len(cpureturn))  # get an index, not a value
del cpureturn[i]
```